# Why does JAXB call getter during unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb

I was surprised to see the following stack trace during JAXB unmarshalling:

```
[#|2013-02-05T18:59:27.551-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|ConfigurationService|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception processing C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\myConfig.xml : @NotNull method com/foo/services/config/Config.getBars must not return null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com.foo.services.config.Config.getBars must not return null
    at com.foo.services.Config.getBars(Config.java:222)
    at com.foo.services.Config$JaxbAccessorM_getBars_setBars_java_util_List.get(MethodAccessor_Ref.java:56)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.startPacking(Lister.java:294)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.startPacking(Lister.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.start(Scope.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ItemsLoader.startElement(ArrayERProperty.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:501)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:150)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:190)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:172)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:177)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:186)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
```

The getter is annotated with org.jetbrains.annotation.NotNull with the intent that it should be marked to not return NULL because the getter is also annotated with @XmlElementRef(required = true). So bascially the @NotNull was put there to tell clients hey this should never be null because its a required element in the XML file being unmarshalled and as such either the parsing will fail because its missing or its going to be there. More info on @NotNull can be found [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html).

The property associated with the getter in this case is a `List<Bar>` which is not initialized by the class to anything as its expected that the unmarshalling process will do so.

In any case I am seeing that if the parsing fails during unmarshalling JAXB calls the getter and this trips the @NotNull which generates the above exception.

Can anyone shed light on this behavior? Thanks,

-Noah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation by default treats public properties as mapped.  The reason it calls get on your `List` property is to see if you a value has been pre-initialized.

**Scenario #1**

JAXB will call `getBars()` to see if a collection has already been created, this will return `null`.  Since `null` was returned JAXB will create an instance of `java.util.ArrayList` which will be set via `setBars`.

```java
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> bars;

    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

}
```

**Scenario #2**

JAXB will call `getBars()` to see if a collection has already been created, this will return an instance of `LinkList`.  Since `null` was not returned JAXB will use the instance of `List` returned from the get method.

```java
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> bars = new LinkedList<Bar>();

    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

}
```

**Scenario #3**

If you would rather that JAXB use the fields instead of the properties, then you can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the class or package (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> bars;

    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting. My JAXB annotated class looks like your first example where 'List' has not been initialized. However, based on the '@NotNull' triggered IllegalStateException it would appear the getter is returning NULL vs. and instance of ArrayList. Perhaps an issue with the annotation vs. JAXB?

Comment: @NBW - By default JAXB uses the getter to check the value of the property during the unmarshal.  In your case it will be `null`.  Then when JAXB sees that the value is null it creates a new instance of `ArrayList`.  I have updated my answer to try an make this more clear.

Comment: yes that's clear now. Thanks for your insights! I have another on Unmarshaller file locking which I will post shortly.

Comment: @NBW - I have added an answer to your new question (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14771268/383861)

Comment: Does this mean that in scenario 2, the setter will never be called? What if the setter does something different than just setting the `this.bars = bars` What if it wants to call a method addBars() to perform some sort of validation before setting it?