# How can I unlock a file locked by JAXB's unmarhsaller

Tags: jaxb

I'm unmarshalling an XML file with JAXB w/Java 1.7.0_03 on Windows 7 x64 using the following code:

```
 try (InputStream xsdStream = ConfigurationService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_XSD_FILE_NAME)) {
            configFile = new File(configFilePath);
            if (configFile.exists()) {
                context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
                Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

                SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
                StreamSource xsdStreamSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
                Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdStreamSource);

                unMarshaller.setSchema(schema);
                Object xmlObject = Config.class.cast(unMarshaller.unmarshal(configFile));
                myConfig = (Config) xmlObject;
            } else {
                log.severe(configFile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist, can not parse configuration info from it.");
            }
  }
```

Code which calls this method subsequently deletes the XML file.

The XML file will properly delete if unmarhalling is successful. However, if the above code throws and Exception, eg. a SAXException, the XML file remains locked indefinitely and the calling code is not able to delete it with File.delete().

This feels like JAXB is not closing the resource/file in this case. Is it my responsibility to do that somehow or is this a bug?

Reviewing the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for Unmarshaller did not shed any light on this and Googling this issue revealed this old, unanswered [question](http://www.java.net/node/677902) from 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

The behaviour you have described sounds like a bug in the JAXB reference implementation.  You can open a ticket using the link below:

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

**Work Around**

Instead of unmarshalling from a `File` you can unmarshal from a `FileInputStream` and control that it is closed correctly yourself after unmarshalling.

---

**LONG ANSWER**

I have not been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing.  I have included what I have tried below.  I am using JDK 1.7.0_07 x64 for the Mac.

**Configuration Service**

Most of the code below is copied from your question.  I have added the call to delete the input file and then output if the file still exists.

```java
package forum14765898;

import java.io.*;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class ConfigurationService {

    private static final String CONFIG_XSD_FILE_NAME = "forum14765898/schema.xsd";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File configFile = null;
        String configFilePath = "src/forum14765898/input.xml";
        JAXBContext context;
        Config myConfig;

        try (InputStream xsdStream = ConfigurationService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_XSD_FILE_NAME)) {
            configFile = new File(configFilePath);
            if (configFile.exists()) {
                context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
                Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

                SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
                StreamSource xsdStreamSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
                Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdStreamSource);

                unMarshaller.setSchema(schema);
                Object xmlObject = Config.class.cast(unMarshaller.unmarshal(configFile));
                myConfig = (Config) xmlObject;
            } else {
                //log.severe(configFile.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist, can not parse configuration info from it.");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        configFile.delete();
        System.out.println(configFile.exists());

    }

}
```

**schema.xsd**

Below is the simple XML schema that I am using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="config">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="bar" type="int"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

**input.xml**

Below is the XML input.  The `bar` element is not valid according to the XML schema.  When a `Schema` is set on the `Unmarshaller` this document will be enough to cause an `Exception` to be thrown while performing an unmarshal operation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <bar>INVALID</bar>
</config>
```

**Config**

```java
package forum14765898;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Config {

    public int bar;

}
```

**Output**

Below is output from running the demo code.  It shows both the validation exception and on the last line we see that the XML file was successfully deleted as it no longer exists.

```java
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/bdoughan/Scratch/src/forum14765898/input.xml; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 23; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'INVALID' is not a valid value for 'integer'.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:512)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at forum14765898.ConfigurationService.main(ConfigurationService.java:31)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/bdoughan/Scratch/src/forum14765898/input.xml; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 23; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'INVALID' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3232)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3147)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3057)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:854)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.endElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:579)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.endElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:143)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    ... 6 more
false
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed feedback. I will try the work around and file a ticket with hopefully full sample code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I converted the code to use a FileInputStream per your recommended work around and that did the trick. I will try to get the time to put together a sanitized project which exemplifies this issue. The other thing to mention is that this is part of a WAR being deployed under Glassfish 3.1.2 b23.

Comment: I'm seeing that exact behavior.  when validation fails, I try to move the file to a "failed" directory and it fails with "java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'path/to/file' after copy to 'path/to/failed'.  and the file isn't actually copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public CashCountCompleted CashDeposit(String path) throws Exception {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      CashCountCompleted cashCountCompleted = null;
      File file = null;
      FileInputStream inputStram = null;
      try {
            file = new File(path);
      inputStram = new FileInputStream(file);
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CashCountCompleted.class);
      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      cashCountCompleted = (CashCountCompleted) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStram);         
      }catch (JAXBException e) {
          //throw new...        
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           //throw new...
      }finally{         
            try{
                if(inputStram !=null){
                    inputStram.close();
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
               //throw new...
            }                 
      }
      return cashCountCompleted;    
}
```

Comment: An explanation for this piece of code would be helpful. I understand you're promoting the use of "finally" after try/catch. I tried this; but it didn't work for me.